# Printing log in JasperReports code

Tags: java, jasper-reports, apache-commons-logging

I'm using *JasperReports* jar in my application, i want to print out everything : diagnostics, debug, trace... but i didn't find how to make it enabled,

*JasperReports* uses the *org.apache.commons.logging.Log* library for logging. For example :

```
/**
 * @author Lucian Chirita (lucianc@users.sourceforge.net)
 * @version $Id: JRMondrianQueryExecuter.java 5879 2013-01-07 20:35:36Z teodord $
*/
public class JRMondrianQueryExecuter extends JRAbstractQueryExecuter
{
  private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(JRMondrianQueryExecuter.class);    
  .....
  ....

 if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
    log.debug("MDX query: " + queryStr);
  }
```

Comment: Check if this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15988948/120380

Comment: @AmiraGL [Apache Commons Logging - User Guide](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/guide.html)