# How to log Jasper Reports (Log4j2.xml Config) for debugging?

Tags: java, debugging, jasper-reports, log4j, log4j2

I'd need to debug Jasper Reports to be able to know why my report appears empty, well, it just displays static information, plus parameters passed by, but I have a sub-report that should be listing some information and this part is empty.

Following some examples in the web I have used the following log4j2.xml configuration file, but:

1. I get no log file create, well, the file is created but it remains empty.
2. How to configure to get output debug from Jasper Reports? If the sub-report gets empty, I guess it must be failing somewhere so I need to discover what's going on.

Here's my log4j2.xml config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">E:\\logs</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="fileLogger" fileName="${basePath}/urnavirtual.log" filePattern="${basePath}/urnavirtual-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>

        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout   pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="net.sf.jasperreports" level="ALL" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="fileLogger" level="ALL" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="ALL" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

In my Last test I added logger with "net.sf.jasperreports", but I guess something is not well configured.

1. Is there any property that should be set to let Jasper Reports know that it must Log their internal errors?
2. What changes should I use in my log4j2.xml file to successfully log Jasper Report errors

I'm using Eclipse Neon with Java 8.

This is my first question so, I apologize if I'm not clear or I'm against any of the StackOverFlow rules.

Thanks a lot,

Edited:
I already have log4j, but even with level=DEBUG, I get no debug output in logs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug jasper reports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090254/how-to-debug-jasper-reports)

Comment: Hello, Alex, thanks for taking your time, no, it's not duplicated; the thread you are pointing out, in the only answer of that thread they are suggesting to use log4j, the difference is that I'm already using it, but I wasn't able to see debug messages, with Tonakai answer I was able to see debug messages in logs. Tonakai answerd marked as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since jasper reports is using log4j, you need to use a bridge for log4j 2 to work properly.
try to add log4j-1.2-api.jar: [apache page for the bridge](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/log4j-1.2-api/index.html)

maven details if you use it: [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-1.2-api)

Comment: Thanks a lot Tonakai, adding log4j-1.2-api.jar, now displays debug messages in log. :)

Comment: Hello @tonakai, even thought this worked for jasper reports the other appenders are not writting to log files, as I said they are created but there's no output. Do you know, What could this be? Should I start another thread to ask this?

Comment: hi @OZWolverine i guess you can create another question, not sure how your current config looks like so can't comment much, but maybe try to start with a simple config that write to single file/console, then try to adjust from there. some of your component might be using some other logging framework which you might need other bridges.

Comment: Hello @tonakai, thanks, I'm going to post another question with my full log4j.xml configuration, maybe you or another community member can help me. Regards.